# rpm fault following db package upgrade

Tags: rpm, aix

I'm in the process of upgrading the internal packages in AIX 7.1. After upgrading the db package with `db-6.2.32-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm` from the AIX toolbox page `rpm` commands no longer works. I've check the files, they exists on the server. How should I recover rpm as I can't find any information on the www. The error messages are shown below.

```
# updtvpkg

Please wait...Could not load program /usr/opt/freeware/bin/rpm:
    Dependent module libdb.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module libdb.so.
System error: No such file or directory
Could not load program /usr/opt/freeware/bin/rpm:
    Dependent module libdb.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module libdb.so.
System error: No such file or directory
Could not load program /usr/opt/freeware/bin/rpm:
    Dependent module libdb.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module libdb.so.
System error: No such file or directory
Could not load program /usr/bin/rpmbuild:
    Dependent module libdb.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module libdb.so.
System error: No such file or directory

# rpm version

Could not load program /usr/opt/freeware/bin/rpm:
    Dependent module libdb.so could not be loaded.
Could not load module libdb.so.
System error: No such file or directory
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /usr/opt/freeware/bin/rpm because of the following errors:
    0509-150   Dependent module libdb.so could not be loaded.
    0509-022 Cannot load module libdb.so.
    0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

Comment: Please do not [multi-post](https://serverfault.com/questions/979194/rpm-fault-following-db-package-upgrade) your question.

Comment: Downdgrade the db package so you are able to update db and rpm.

Comment: You could use Midnight Commander to extract libdb.so from the db...rpm file. (Or copy it from another AIX computer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the missing libdb.so file is provided by the [rpm package](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1fileset1404816868), you'll need to reinstall rpm. You'll want to toggle `OVERWRITE same or newer versions` to `yes`, since the package is already installed, but file(s) are missing.